# Which OpenSSL env has to be be chosen: development | runtime | base? What's the difference?

Tags: openssl, cygwin, ruby-2.0

I'm trying to install **Ruby-2.0.0-rc2** with [ruby-build](https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build) on Windows under Cygwin. And I got BUILD FAILED error because had no **OpenSSL** lib pre-installed in Cygwin.

```
BUILD FAILED

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /tmp/ruby-build.20130317003705.5576
Results logged to /tmp/ruby-build.20130317003705.5576.log

Last 10 log lines:
installing default gems:      /usr/local/ruby-2.0.0-rc2/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0 (build_info, cache, doc, gems, specific ations)
                              bigdecimal 1.1.0
                              io-console 0.4.1
                              json 1.7.5
                              minitest 4.3.2
                              psych 2.0.0
                              rake 0.9.6
                              rdoc 4.0.0.rc.2.1
                              test-unit 2.0.0.0
The Ruby openssl extension was not compiled. Missing the OpenSSL lib?
```

I've checked its `setup.exe` and there are several variants of **OpenSSL** environments. Which one has to be chosen?

I had `libopenssl100 The OpenSSL runtime environment` pre-installed but that didn't save me from BUILD FAILED. So now there are two left that may be installed:

```
openssl The OpenSSL base environment
openssl-devel The OpenSSL development environment
```

Which one to chose? And what does it mean `development`? It's in development process or for development

Answer (score 0):

Only this one:

```
1.0.1e-2 openssl-devel The OpenSSL development environment
```

All others are just in vain.